# What's the difference between Rack and Passenger?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger, rack, dreamhost

I'm trying to deploy a Sinatra app to Dreamhost and it says the following:

> Since DH supports Passenger, which in
>   turn supports Rack-based ruby
>   applications, DH does indeed support
>   Sinatra.

I'm having difficulty parsing that statement - what's the difference between Rack and Passenger (and why is Sinatra "Rack-based")?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Rack](https://rack.github.io/) is a [standardized API](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC) for web servers to talk to middleware and web frameworks in Ruby. [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) is an Apache module that implements the Rack API. [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) is a web framework that is built [on top of the Rack API](http://www.sinatrarb.com/api/index.html), so because Dreamhost supports Phusion Passenger, that means that it supports Rack, and thus Sinatra.